# increase font size in th colspan without css

Tags: html

ok. I was given a pre-work assignment for a programming bootcamp to set up a simple biography without using CSS. We also have to use a html validator which i did. Now i can't figure out what the error means. I am putting my name as a table title and i used h2 tags inside th colspan so i could make the name bigger. The validator says its wrong but it shows up fine in the browser and I don't know how to fix it for the validator. So here is the snipet of code with the problems. (also line 16 is table border line 18 is tr border and line 20 is th colspan.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset ="utf-8">
        <title>Levi's Biography</title>
    <!-- lines 6 through 11 are simply added for developing the page to a future standard -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="mybio.css">

        <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

          <table border="4px">
            <thead>
                <tr border="3px"> 
                <!-- html validator says lines 16, 18, and 20 are wrong even though browser shows up well. How do i fix this? -->
                  <th colspan="4"><h2>Levi Donaldson</h2></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>             
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-family:copperplate"><h3>Born</h3></td>
                    <td style="font-family:copperplate"><h3>Grew up</h3></td>
                    <td style="font-family:copperplate"><h3>Hobbies</h3></td>
                    <td style="font-family:copperplate"><h3>Foods</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Moenci, AZ</td>
                    <td>Mesa, AZ
                        <br>
                    Wasilla, AK
                        <br> 
                    Eagar, AZ
                        <br> 
                    Cliff, NM
                    </td>

                    <td>Quality family time
                        <br> 
                    Traveling
                        <br> 
                    Fishing
                        <br> 
                    Cooking
                        <br> 
                    Passive income streams
                        <br> 
                    Creating things or improving their designs
                    </td>

                    <td>A great steak
                        <br> 
                    Sushi <em>(with scallops if possible)</em>
                        <br> 
                    Brazilian rice and beans
                        <br> 
                    Home grown fruit
                        <br> 
                    Fresh garden veggies and herbs
                        <br> Cheesecake <strong>(but for heavens sake, NO New York style)</strong>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

        <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_b3dSgzaqFKs/SRfDqJxbSOI/AAAAAAAAADc/iNvyqMQqzKs/S220/katie%26levi2+001.jpg" alt="levi wedding" />

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us exactly what the validate says?

Comment: wrong how? which html validation are you using?

Comment: Given the current information, I assume you have a doctype, an end tag for the table, and you are using HTML 4.01 transitional. Can you paste more of the code? The entire code is preferred

Comment: Error Line 16, Column 24: The border attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
    <table border="4px">
✉
Error Line 18, Column 23: Attribute border not allowed on element tr at this point.
      <tr border="3px"> 
Attributes for element tr:
Global attributes
Error Line 20, Column 28: The element h2 must not appear as a descendant of the th element.
        <th colspan="4"><h2>Levi Donaldson</h2></th>

Comment: validator.w3.org was the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you had put `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the document, the validator will validate it using HTML 5 rules.

1. In HTML 5, the border attribute no longer valid. You must use css, for example `style='border: 1px solid black'` instead.
2. There are no `border` attribute for `TR` tag. So it is invalid.
3. You should not use `H2` tag inside `TH` tag. Use css instead. For example: `style='font-size: 200%;'`.

You can refer [CSS font size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp)